# Clion autocomple doesn't suggest `to_vec` for slice

Tags: rust, clion, rust-cargo

I have the following piece of code in Clion, written in Rust:

```
fn brootforce(points: &Vec<Point>) -> (Point, Point) {
    let mut min_dst = f64::INFINITY;
    let mut p1 = points[0];
    let mut p2 = points[1];
    for (idx, point1) in points.iter().enumerate() {
        // for point2 in points[idx + 1..]. {
        for point2 in points[idx + 1..].to_vec() {
            let dst = distance(*point1, point2);
            if min_dst > dst {
                min_dst = dst;
                p1 = *point1;
                p2 = point2;
            }
        }
    }
    return (p1, p2)
}
```

It is supposed to seek for the pair of closest points in the array of points.

So, on the line:

```
for point2 in points[idx + 1..].to_vec() {
```

...when I'm trying to use to_vec() method, the autocomplete doesn't work:

[Autocomplete doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLMIE.png)

But when I'm doing it without any bounds, it works just fine:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQEKY.png)

Why is that so? Is that a Clion Rust plugin issue? And how to solve that?

I've tried to install other plugins and reinstalled Rust plugin a couple of times, but that didn't come in handy.

Comment: Just a note you probably want `into_iter()` instead to avoid allocating a `Vec` that immediately gets dropped again.

Comment: @cafce25 except that `into_iter` won't work because it takes ownership of the slice. Instead the OP should use `points[idx + 1..].iter().cloned()` to avoid the temporary allocation.